# Error at Copying Query in my app - for 2sxc dnn module

Tags: dotnetnuke-module, 2sxc

I create and export app for 2sxc for testing on dnn 8.00.02 and 2sxc 8.04.05

[download](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3XM46ujQLRFUlJKYzRsTkdzTFk)

My problem is that I don't know what is wrong with this app or data,
that when I try to Copy Query I get the error, but don't know what is this error telling me?

[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkBVD.jpg)

Can somebody test this to see if there is also an error on some other computer and if you can tell me what is wrong and how to fix this?

I can't copy this template on original development computer and also on new dnn installation with imported app.

Comment: It seems that this is bug in 2sxc and not my applications. When I tried the same in other applications I get the same error.
Also posted bug at : https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/844

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I can reproduce the issue - it seems to be a bug in 2sxc 8.4.? which affects everything. Will try to fix it by 8.4.7; so it's probably best to mark this question as closed.